# Remove active open menu on pathname route change

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have this useEffect which I use inside my Next 13 application and my component. `use client` at the top doesn't work with `next/router`. When route is changed, it fades away, instead of instantly being removed from the DOM. Is there like some kind alternative approach on how to remove this active open menu on route change. Inside use client page?

My code:

```
"use client"

import type { SettingsPayload } from "types"

import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

import Link from "next/link"
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation"

import IconsLibrary from "@/components/shared/IconsLibrary"
import Menu from "@/components/shared/Menu"

interface NavbarProps {
  data: SettingsPayload
}

const Header = (props: NavbarProps) => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const { data } = props

  const pathname = usePathname()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (menuOpen) {
      setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)
    }
  }, [pathname])

  //   let currentTheme

  //   if (isBrowser) {
  //     currentTheme = window.localStorage.getItem("theme")
  //   }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fixed top-0 z-10 flex w-full items-center justify-between px-[20px] pt-[20px] md:px-10 md:pt-10">
        <Link href="/">
          <IconsLibrary
            fill={pathname === "/" ? "white" : "#40e640"}
            type="main-logo"
            className="h-[60px] w-[60px] md:h-[80px] md:w-[80px]"
          />
        </Link>

        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <div className="relative hidden lg:block">
            <button onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}>
              <IconsLibrary
                type="menu-icon"
                fill={pathname === "/" ? "black" : "#ebebeb"}
                fillChild={pathname === "/" ? "white" : "black"}
                className={`relative z-20 duration-300 ease-in-out ${
                  menuOpen ? "rotate-45" : "rotate-0"
                }`}
              />
            </button>
            <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} menuData={data} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className={`absolute right-0 top-0 h-screen w-screen bg-black bg-opacity-90
          backdrop-blur-[1px] transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out ${
            menuOpen ? "visible opacity-25" : "invisible opacity-0"
          }`}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="fixed bottom-8 z-10 flex h-20 w-full justify-center lg:hidden lg:h-full">
        <button onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}>
          <IconsLibrary
            type="menu-icon"
            fill={pathname === "/" ? "black" : "#ebebeb"}
            fillChild={pathname === "/" ? "white" : "#black"}
            className={`relative z-20 duration-300 ease-in-out ${
              menuOpen ? "rotate-45" : "rotate-0"
            }`}
          />
        </button>
        <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} menuData={data} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```